# Use TextSwitcher with custom Typeface

Tags: android, fonts, textview, typeface

I would like to use a `TextSwitcher` as opposed to a `TextView` because of the animations available, but does someone know how to use a custom `Typeface` for the text? I don't want to use the default font.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the `android:fontFamily` attribute for each child `TextView`.

```
<TextSwitcher . . .>
    <TextView
        android:fontFamily="..."
        . . . />

    <TextView
        android:fontFamily="..."
        . . . />

</TextSwitcher>
```

The `TextSwitcher` will alternate between the two `TextView` children, using the font family (Typeface) you specify.

Comment: Is this approach exactly equivalent to using `mTextSwitcher.setFactory(mFactoryThatInflatesATextViewFromXmlLayout)` or `mTextSwitcher.setFactory(mFactoryThatCreatesATextViewProgrammatically)` ? Your approach certainly looks simpler to me, but for some reason the Android sample app on `TextSwitcher` uses a factory to create the `TextViews` programmatically.

Comment: @Sebastien - Using a `ViewFactory` provides more flexibility at run time, but otherwise it is equivalent to what I posted.

Comment: @Ted Hopp. Thanks. I have implemented your solution and I confirm it works fine indeed. (I hate customizing the appearance of Views in Java when I can do it in XML).